# HTML/CSS animate header elements

Tags: html, css

I am making a website and I want to select the header links as I scroll down. So if my browser is looking at the About Us section, the about us header elements will be selected. Or if I were looking at the very top of the webpage, the home nav link will be selected. I'm having difficulty finding information on the topic, so all help is welcome.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. We don't work with hypotheticals around these parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you are describing will require Javascript. I'd suggest taking a look at Bootstrap as it includes this behavior out of the box...

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/scrollspy/

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what i needed